# How to change the Drupal core module behavior?

Tags: search, drupal-6, module, hook, redeclare

How can I change the behavior of `search_menu()` hook, not changing the `search.module` code?

I want to change it from:

```
function search_menu() {
  //...
  foreach (module_implements('search') as $name) {
    $items['search/'. $name .'/%menu_tail'] = array(
      'title callback' => 'module_invoke',
      'title arguments' => array($name, 'search', 'name', TRUE),
      'page callback' => 'search_view',
      'page arguments' => array($name),
      'access callback' => '_search_menu',
      'access arguments' => array($name),
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'parent' => 'search',
      'file' => 'search.pages.inc',
    );
  }
  return $items;
}
```

to:

```
function search_menu() {
  //...
  foreach (module_implements('search') as $name) {
    $items['search/'. $name .'/%menu_tail'] = array(
      'title callback' => 'module_invoke',
      'title arguments' => array($name, 'search', 'name', TRUE),
      'page callback' => 'search_view',
      'page arguments' => array($name),
      'access callback' => '_search_menu',
      'access arguments' => array($name),
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'parent' => 'search',
      'file' => 'search.pages.inc',
    );
  }
  return $items;
}
```

to hide tabs on search page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Do not hack core](http://drupal.org/node/144376). Check out [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was looking for! :) The only hack I had to do in the core: I changed search pager size from `10` to `variable_get('search_results_per_page', 10)`.

Comment: That sounds like a patch that might be worth contributing.